# Calling the roll: marking someone (as) absent

Tags: grammar, prepositions, collocations

I am wondering what is the proper choice in the following examples:

**Example 1:**

> I missed the previous session. So the teacher..........

**a.** marked me absent 
**b.** marked me **as** absent

**Example 2:**

> Teacher: Remember! If you are late for classes by more than 15 minutes, you will be............

**a.** marked absent 
**b.** marked **as** absent

I would appreciate if someone could let me know whether the preposition "as" is optional or superfluous here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In both examples, the preposition **as** is optional.